# Square dot between two square brackets notification icon?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notification-icons

The icon looks like a square dot in middle and two square brackets surrounding it.

I tried looking for the icon on Google but couldn't find it.

How can I removes it and what is it?
E.D.I.T.  The icon is like [[•]] the dot is square its on system side. It appears and goes automatically. Dont know how to add screenshot. I am new here.Device is Yu Yureka Plus Running Cyanogen 12.1 and lollipop 5.1.1
[Img]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1P4PszWSbUbeEJ4RW5NRVZFazg/view?usp=docslist_api[\img]

Comment: Could you add the screenshot? Also, where's the icon located? Left (user app) or right (system icon)? Lastly, what's your device model?

Comment: Sounds like a recording taking place. `[•]`? A screenshot would definitely help.

Comment: The icon is like [[•]] the dot is square its on system side. It appears and goes automatically. Dont know how to add screenshot. I am new here.Device is Yu Yureka Plus Running Cyanogen 12.1 and lollipop 5.1.1

Comment: Please post a screenshot.

Comment: This can now be safely closed as a dupe of [What is this notification , how do o get rid of this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/110544)

Comment: Added the screenshot in the link

Answer (score 1):

That icon indicates that your phone is in vibrate mode.

Here is a similar question asked a year ago about that icon on a similar phone (The Yu Yuphoria):

[What is this notification , how do o get rid of this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110544/what-is-this-notification-how-do-o-get-rid-of-this)